# Devise sign_out via API not doing anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rest, devise

We've got a Rails 4.2.3 with Devise 3.5.5 for allowing Facebook auth.
Our backend is accessed by iOS app and has a Rails web front-end.

Both signing in and out is working properly on the web, signing in works absolutely fine also in the iOS app; but **attempting DELETE request on http://BASE_URL/users/sign_out/ makes no change in the user state** — the session is not destroyed and the user is kept authorized.

1) Web signing out conducted via the following template works properly:

```
<%= link_to('Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
```

2) When I request DELETE on /users/sign_out/ (using Paw or cURL) I get HTTP 204 (a proper answer for delete query as I get it).

3) Devise sign out method is being accessed: I've set a logger triger in app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb `destroy` method and it give a log entry every time the request is made.

4) When I change `config.sign_out_via` method to `:get` everything starts working as intended: the session gets terminated after GET /users/sign_out/ request.

5) Just to cover all other solution avenues from similar StackOverflow questions I've checked that `#= require jquery_ujs` is in place.

I was thinking about keeping deauth method on `:get` but as I understand it has two major flaws: CSRF insecurity and general non-restfulness of using GET to destroy an object.

Please advise on what changes I can implement to investigate the issue and fix it!

Comment: Please have a look at http://blog.codebykat.com/2012/07/23/remote-api-authentication-with-rails-3-using-activeresource-and-devise/

Comment: @Shrikant1712, thanks! But it seems to me that that the article author completely redefines Devise session controller methods so it won't really answer my main question (why GET is working while DELETE is not).

Comment: I don't suppose you ever figured this one out? I'm having this issue 4 years later. I've got a button being rendered in react that sends a delete request to my logout URL, and right next to it I have a button rendered by rails that sends a delete request to the same URL. Only the rails one works, but both send the same request.

Comment: Nevermind, I did the naive thing and forgot to halt the redirect on button press with `e.preventDefault()`. Keeping my post in case someone else does the same.